# SQL: Insert only new rows/records into a table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, zend-framework, zend-db

I'm parsing a json feed routinely and need to insert only the newest users from the feed and ignore existing users.

I think what I need is `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` or `INSERT IGNORE` based on some searching but I'm not quite sure which is why I'm asking - so for example:

```
users
1     John
2     Bob
```

Partial JSON:

```
{ userid:1, name:'John' },
{ userid:2, name:'Bob' },
{ userid:3, name:'Jeff' }
```

From this feed I only want to insert Jeff. I could do a simple loop through all users and do a simple SELECT query and see if the user id is already in the table, if not I do an INSERT, however I suspect it won't be an efficient and practical method.

By the way, I'm using Zend_Db for the database interaction if anyone would like to cater a specific answer :) I don't mind a generic strategic solution though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) alternative allows you to refer the update vs. insert decision to the database:

```
INSERT INTO table (userid, name) VALUES (2, 'Bobby');
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name = 'Bobby';
```

would update the name field to 'Bobby', if an entry with userid 2 already exists.

You can use it as an alternative to the `INSERT IGNORE` if you supply a noneffective operation to the UPDATE:

```
INSERT INTO table (userid, name) VALUES (2, 'Bobby');
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name = name;
```

This would do nothing if userid 2 already exists, thus avoiding the warning and swallowing of other errors you'd get when using `INSERT IGNORE`.

---

Another alternative would be [`REPLACE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replace.html):

```
REPLACE INTO table (userid, name) VALUES (2, 'Bobby');
```

This would do a normal insert if the userid 2 does not exist yet. If it does exist, it will delete the old entry first and then insert a new one.

---

Be aware that both versions are MySQL specific extensions to SQL.

Answer (score 4):

For Zend Framework, what I do is a try/catch of the insert statement and take further action based on the exception code:

```
class Application_Model_DbTable_MyModel extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract

    public function insert($aData, $bIgnore = false) 
    {

        try 
        {
            $id =  parent::insert($aData);
        } 
        catch(Zend_Db_Statement_Mysqli_Exception $e) 
        {
            // code 1062: Mysqli statement execute error : Duplicate entry
            if($bIgnore && $e->getCode() == 1062) 
            {
                // continue;
            } 
            else 
            {
                throw $e;
            }
        }
        return !empty($id) ? $id : false;
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to give up $bIgnore because of Strict Standards: Declaration of Your_Model::insert() should be compatible with Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::insert(array $data) in ...

Answer (score 2):

You need to define userid as a PRIMARY or UNIQUE key and use something like:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table (userid, name) VALUES (2, 'Bob');
```

If the userid 2 already exists it will ignore and move on to the next insert.

You can also use ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE on your table schema. **One other alternative might be to use the REPLACE INTO syntax.**

```
REPLACE INTO table (userid, name) VALUES (2, 'Bob');
```

**This will try to INSERT, if the record already exists it will DELETE it before INSERTing it again.**

Comment: Is `INSERT IGNORE` supported in Zend_Db?

Comment: The `IGNORE` will cause the db engine to issue warnings instead of errors, so execution of the query won't stop. A drawback of this approach is that *any* error encountered will be ignored/turned to warning, not only a duplicate key.

Comment: @Henrik: I wasn't aware of the warnings vs errors feature but I've provided an alternative method to accomplish the same without using IGNORE.

Comment: @eyze: I was just writing up the alternatives as well ;)

Comment: @eyze: A minor but potentially important correction - `REPLACE` will **not** do an UPDATE in case of an existing key, it will do a DELETE, followed by an INSERT.

Answer (score 1):

My solution :

```
/**
 * Perform an insert with the IGNORE word
 *
 * @param $data array
 * @return number the number of rows affected
 */
public function insertIgnore(array $data)
{
    // Start of query
    $sql = sprintf("INSERT IGNORE INTO %s (", $this->getAdapter()->quoteIdentifier($this->info('name')));
    // Retrieve column identifiers
    $identifiers = array_keys($data);
    foreach ($identifiers as $key => $value) {
        // Quote identifier
        $identifiers[$key] = $this->getAdapter()->quoteIdentifier($value);
    }
    // Concat column identifiers
    $sql .= implode(', ', $identifiers);
    $sql .= ") VALUES (";
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        // Quote values
        $data[$key] = $this->getAdapter()->quote($value);
    }
    // Concat values identifiers
    $sql .= implode(', ', $data);
    $sql .= ")";
    // Process the query
    return $this->getAdapter()->query($sql)->rowCount();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the loop, you can do a update first, if no row affected, means it's a new entry. Keep track of those 'failed updates' then do an insert of them as new entries.

I'm not familiar with Zend_Db but I assume it can return whether a update affected how many row(s).

Comment: Somehow I misread the question for the need to update existing users if found, else insert as new. well... down-voted